# Arduino int16_t to uint8_t conversion weirdness

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I have some really simply code that reads from an ADS sensor, which returns a value as `int16_t`.  I know this value is always positive, so it saves memory. I am storing it in an array of `uint8_t`.  But, I am getting a really odd conversion - any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
int16_t ads0 = ads.readADC_SingleEnded(0);
int16_t ads1 = ads.readADC_SingleEnded(1);
PLUG_ADS[0][PLUG_ADS_IDX] = (uint8_t)ads0;
PLUG_ADS[1][PLUG_ADS_IDX] = (uint8_t)ads1;
Serial.print("ADS 0: ");
Serial.print(ads0);
Serial.print(" / ");
Serial.print(PLUG_ADS[0][PLUG_ADS_IDX]);
Serial.print(" ADS 1: ");
Serial.print(ads1);
Serial.print(" / ");
Serial.println(PLUG_ADS[1][PLUG_ADS_IDX]);
```

And here is the output:

```
ADS 0: 791 / 23 ADS 1: 845 / 77
ADS 0: 792 / 24 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 794 / 26 ADS 1: 843 / 75
ADS 0: 790 / 22 ADS 1: 843 / 75
ADS 0: 792 / 24 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 843 / 75
ADS 0: 794 / 26 ADS 1: 843 / 75
ADS 0: 791 / 23 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 790 / 22 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 845 / 77
ADS 0: 791 / 23 ADS 1: 843 / 75
ADS 0: 792 / 24 ADS 1: 843 / 75
ADS 0: 791 / 23 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 792 / 24 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 791 / 23 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 792 / 24 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 794 / 26 ADS 1: 846 / 78
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 842 / 74
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 845 / 77
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 845 / 77
ADS 0: 793 / 25 ADS 1: 844 / 76
ADS 0: 797 / 29 ADS 1: 847 / 79
ADS 0: 792 / 24 ADS 1: 843 / 75
```

What the heck am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint8_t` is an unsigned 8 bit integer. It can represent values from 0 to 255.
`int16_t` is a signed 16 bit integer. It can represent values from -32768 to 32767. See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values) for a list of values that reach integer type can represent.

When you convert your value (with `(uint8_t)ads0;`) you are trying to convert values in the order of 790 into a type that can only represent values up to 255. This causes a loss of data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my bonehead mistake... I was simply thinking the uint8_t was larger... dope

Comment: It's true that, since you only use the positive values of `int16_t` you should be able to save memory, since half the possible states are unused. The error is to assume half the states means half the bits. Each bit doubles the number of states an integer can have, the waste is 1 bit. You would need some sort of unsigned 15 bit integer to recover that wasted memory.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - and, of course, that's the reason that this doesn't really save any memory; getting rid of one bit won't affect the amount of storage used.